# Finding out what hypervisor is running

Tags: linux, virtualbox, virtual-machine, virtualization, hypervisor

I can't start Virtual Box because it says another hypervisor is running. How can I find out what this other hypervisor is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure how to tell which hypervisor has grabbed the VMX root, but a common issue is the kernel virtualization module taking over. You can remove it like so to make room for other virtualization products to run:

```
sudo modprobe -r kvm_intel
```